# Enable framebuffer console in Android kernel source

Tags: cyanogenmod, bootloader, kernel

Is it possible to somehow enable the framebuffer console in android kernel sources from samsung, to see kernel messages instead of just the bootlogo?

Comment: Use the *LiveBoot* app by Chainfire to do this. Note: you need to have a rooted device.

Comment: I cant use this as android doesnt boot. Its stuck at the boot logo. I would need something more low level.

Comment: Well then you are out of luck for external applications. You need some special kernel/bootloader to do that. I don't think there will be one for your device, though.

Comment: When you say it's stuck at the boot logo-- do you mean the bootloader's logo?  Or do you mean android has loaded and it's bootlooping?  If the latter, you don't need a framebuffer console, you need [logcat](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Logcat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't really say what you were trying to do exactly-- but if I understand right, and you're any good with soldering, it sounds like you *might* want to find the [UART](http://linux-sunxi.org/UART) pins on your device, then tap that and use a serial connection to your computer to read the bootloader output (via [minicom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minicom) or some other terminal emulator) and access the live console that way.  You may also be able to get serial data from the [USB](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1901376) during boot.

Of course, if you are just stuck with a non-booting system and trying to recover a device, you might use odin/heimdall to reflash your boot image (including a new kernel) or install a custom recovery image and use that to flash a ROM with a good kernel.

It sounds like you're possibly deliberately messing with your own built kernels- maybe to upgrade to a new kernel base or something?  If that's the case, an alternative to seeing the kernel messages onscreen is to enable [PSTORE](http://lwn.net/Articles/434821/) (the file system-based replacement for /proc/last_kmesg), which will let you view the dmesg/kernel console + any panic messages after a bad boot on the next reboot (so long as the ram doesn't get overwritten).  Take a look at this [example](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_kernel_samsung_trlte/commit/17a8ee52fac02b9ec4e8c958ed1ec70bcf2156eb) from the trlte (Samsung Note 4) kernel for how to implement it in the newer kernels.  (If it's an older kernel you may just need to turn on [last_kmesg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682306/android-how-to-get-kernel-logs-after-kernel-panic).)